# Weird matplotlib.pyplot importation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I found a really weird behaviour when trying to import the module `pyplot` from `matplotlib`. First it says it does not exist, but after importing `pylab` (another `matplotlib` module), it suddently works!

```
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.__version__
'1.2.1'
>>> matplotlib.pyplot
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'pyplot'
>>> import pylab
>>> matplotlib.pyplot
<module 'matplotlib.pyplot' from '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.pyc'>
```

Anyone else has this behaviour in his/her computer?

---

****** This happened on a OS X Mountain Lion, running Python 2.7. I installed `matplotlib` with `pip`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, to access a module within a package, you must import that module.  You can't just import the package and access the module with dot syntax.  Just do `from matplotlib import pyplot` (or `import matplotlib.pyplot` if you really like typing dots).

The reason it works after importing `pylab` is that `pylab` imports `pyplot`, after which `pyplot` is available as an attribute of the enclosing package `matplotlib`.

Basically, if you do `import package`, you can't expect you will be able to do `package.module`.  But if you do `import package` *and* `from package import module`, then you can do `package.module`.

Comment: Well, that answers everything. Thank you kind sir (now, let's wait the 9 minutes ...)